# Disable Horizontal Scrolling on Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

So, I have a website [here](http://slicedbread.xyz). I have some clouds which move across the page with jQuery. The problem begins when you view the page on mobile. You're able to scroll past the actual page and follow the clouds. This isn't hard to do, and a lot of people have noticed it. There is no problem on PC, although there used to be. I disabled the arrow keys and the space bar as movement though, so you cannot replicate the mobile bug on PC anymore. If anyone could help me, that would be great, thanks.

EDIT: this is the js for the clouds. Maybe it's what's causing this to happen. What I really want, though, is to disable horizontal scrolling on mobile completely, if possible

```
$(function() {
  var img = $("#cloud"),
      width = img.get(0).width,
      screenWidth = $(window).width(),
      duration = 50000;

  function animatePlane() {
      img.css("left", -width).animate({
          "left": screenWidth
      }, duration, animatePlane);
  }

  animatePlane();
});
```

Comment: I found many question like this. most of them are closed, voted down since it has no codes provided.

Comment: your code is okay in chrome and firefox. no `horizontal scrollbar` I found.

Comment: Ok so if it isn't that, I ask you to go to my site on your phone or mobile device and when the clouds reach the right end of the screen, swipe left. That's the issue I'm trying to solve. Is this an issue with browsing on mobile in general, is it a bug that can be fixed? That's what I want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at your website, this is how you fix your current issue (which *is* present on desktop browsers):

```
.header {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I will explain why each one of these rules is needed:

- `width: 100%;` one hundred percent of the browser window
- `overflow: hidden` when elements (like the `img`) move past the edges (100%) of the browser window, it will be `hidden`
- `position: relative` - do this on the `.header` or the above rules need to be on the `body`
- `height: auto` you set a static `height` for an element that has child element expanding past that height, if you don't do this and you use `overflow: hidden`, the vertical elements within the `.header` will not be shown

---

It’s important to note that this is a **band-aid** fix to a much larger issue; that issue is the current way you are developing the site. There's many other issues going on, here is a short list:

- don’t wrap your entire site content in a `header` element
- use semantic class names, and avoid using names that are reserved for [HTML tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/)(you have an element named `.body`
- get used to [HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/) - it's current
- structure your [HTML elements logically](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/courses/semantic-html-how-to-structure-web-pages)

**Note:** I am not bashing you or your learning experience, this is better than most of my first websites, but I am just trying to get you on the right track to make the rest of development easier

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive response. I appreciate the time you put into providing those links and explaining your suggestion. However, I don't really understand what you mean by wrapping my site in a `header` element. Do you mean me putting everything into the body tag?

Comment: @blackjackrobo yeah that's the jist - you are wrapping everything in the `.header` element which isn't necessarily a *bad* thing, since it is a `div` but I would use more semantic naming conventions for the elements - because it's not really acting as a `header` but more of a `wrapper` - review the link above about semantic class names and HTML5 elements if your interested in more detail about what I mean - I'm glad I was able to help you out:)